# Count number of rows using MATCH AGAINST on FullText index column

Tags: mysql, mariadb, full-text-indexing, match-against

I have a table in my database that contains quite a lot of data. I have to run a query that should simply count the number of rows where a certain keyword is present in the `Message` column.

Normally I would run this:

```
SELECT count(1) FROM applogs WHERE Message LIKE '%level_100%'
```

This works. It gives me `2972 rows` back. But this is obviously very slow for larger datasets.

So I've added a `FullText` index to the `Message` column so I can use `Match Against` like so:

```
SELECT count(1) FROM applogs WHERE MATCH(Message) AGAINST('level_100');
```

Now this runs very fast. But this gives me a count of `5672` back.

Because the `level_100` term can occur more than once per row. But I'm not interested in how many occurences. I just want to know how many rows.

Is there a way to do this using `MATCH AGAINST`?

Comment: It shouldn't count rows twice.

Comment: `count(1)` just counts the number of rows, it doesn't count occurrences.

Comment: Did you "simplify" the query for the Question?  Such as removing a `JOIN`?

Comment: What version; which engine?

Comment: I did not simplify the query. Right now when I do a `Message LIKE '%5672%'` it gives me a count of ***3343*** where as `MATCH(Message) AGAINST('5672')` gives me a count of ***2891***. Why is there a difference?

Comment: i am facing this same issue with full text search. did you find a solution ?